# Why does Type.GetElementType return null?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a method that takes as an input parameter an object of type `IEnumerable`. I want to enumerate the enumeration and for each item use reflection to get the value for each property.

I have the following code:

```
protected void WriteData(IEnumerable data)
{
    var enumerationTypeInfo = data.GetType();
    var itemTypeInfo = enumerationTypeInfo.GetElementType();

    ...
}
```

The problem is `enumerationTypeInfo.GetElementType()` always returns `null`. In particular, I'm passing in a `List<Entry>` into `WriteData`, where `Entry` is a class I created. When I use the debugger and set a breakpoint I can see that `enumerationTypeInfo` correctly shows that it's a List of type `Entry`, but why does `GetElementType` return `null`?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`GetElementType` is for use with arrays, not other generic classes.  To get a generic type's generic parameters, you can use [`Type.GetGenericArguments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx).

Comment: Further - GetElementType will always return null if used on a generic type.

See MSDN article at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getelementtype.aspx

Comment: types like StringDictionary and NameValueCollection have no generic arguments but are still IEnumerable...so GetGenericArguments will not work for those

Answer (score 14):

`GetElementType()` returns the element type of arrays.  `List<T>` is not an array type, and therefore has no "element type."

If you want to get the type of elements a random `IEnumerable<T>` produces, try something like this:

```
public static Type GetEnumerableType(Type type)
{
    if (type == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("type");

    if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
        return type.GetGenericArguments()[0];

    var iface = (from i in type.GetInterfaces()
                 where i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>)
                 select i).FirstOrDefault();

    if (iface == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Does not represent an enumerable type.", "type");

    return GetEnumerableType(iface);
}
```

Note that types can implement more than one version of the same generic interface; a type can implement both `IEnumerable<int>` and `IEnumerable<string>` for example.  How you handle that case is up to you.  The method I provide will take whichever interface type the runtime hands it first.

---

See [an example using the above method](http://ideone.com/TUC31) on ideone.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for types like StringDictionary and NameValueCollection, which have no generic arguments but are still IEnumerable...

Comment: @user3163495 Yes, that should be obvious. If they don't declare an implementation of `IEnumerable<T>` then you need a special case to handle them.