# Getting a null reference while using GetElementType()

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, graphql, mutation

I'm trying to make my graphQL mutation generic. But on runtime i get an error. 
The error says: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
public class ApplicationMutation<T> : ObjectGraphType where T: BaseModel
{
    public ApplicationMutation()
    {
        this.Name = "RootMutation";

        var nameofT = typeof(T).GetElementType().Name;

        this.Field<AddPayloadType<T>>(
            "add" + nameofT,
            arguments: new InputQueryArguments<AddInputType<T>>(),
            resolve: context =>
            {
                var input = context.GetArgument<AddInput<T>>("input");

                var result = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
                {
                    Name = "1337 p40c355I73m";
                };

                return new AddPayload<T>(input, result);
            });

        this.Field<UpdatePayloadType<T>>(
            "update" + nameofT,
            arguments: new InputQueryArguments<UpdateInputType<T>>(),
            resolve: context =>
            {
                var input = context.GetArgument<UpdateInput<T>>("input");

                var result = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
                {
                    Name = "rul0r item";
                };

                return new UpdatePayload<T>(input, result);
            });

        this.Field<DeletePayloadType<T>>(
            "delete" + nameofT,
            arguments: new InputQueryArguments<DeleteInputType<T>>(),
            resolve: context =>
            {
                var input = context.GetArgument<DeleteInput<T>>("input");

                var result = true;

                return new DeletePayload<T>(input, result);
            });
    }
}
```

The exception is thrown from the following line:
`var nameofT = typeof(T).GetElementType().Name;`

If more information is required, just ask for it.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7072088/1514875  - It seems like you only should use `GetElementType()` for arrays.

Comment: Use GetGenericArguments() instead of GetElementType().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use the `GetElementType()` for arrays, pointers and references types..

> null if the current Type is not an array or a pointer, or is not passed by reference, or represents a generic type or a type parameter in the definition of a generic type or generic method
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getelementtype.aspx

It will return `null` for generic's

Comment: Do you have any suggest what could i use instead?

Comment: @MMK suggests `GetGenericArguments()` but I am not sure if that's work.. :)